# Visual Studio performance under Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I recently moved from Vista 32 bits to Windows 7 64 bits, and I notice Visual Studio 2008 is slower when it comes to initialising certain things, like the delay when you first use the toolbox is longer, opening a project for the 1st time is longer etc. For the rest it runs smoothly. For the record, I'm using a fairly new dual core pc with 3 GB ram.

Does anyone else experience this? Any solutions maybe?

Comment: I've seen the same behavior. And it's even worse in VS2010 B2. Just opening it takes a minute. No idea why (although the IDE program itself is 32 bit - it installs into Program Files (x86) - maybe that's a clue?)

Comment: I think the suggestions to close are a little unfair. Although not programming language related, clearly programming related. It's an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed a performance increase when moved VS to Win 7 64bit (same machine).  Some of the issues you point out might be related to your project building the intellisense db as well as help files installed (MSDN or additional MShelp versoin 2).

If it's real burning issue, use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see if VS is spending extra time loading/looking for things.